# Exclude omitted lines in git-diff

Tags: git, git-diff

If we have this code below:

```
1: int a = 1;
2: int b = 2;
3: int c = 3;
4: int d = 4;
```

And we removed line 2 and 3, and change line 1 into `int a = 0;`

e.g.

```
1: int a = 0;
2: int d = 4;
```

git diff will show output like this:

```
1: - int a = 1;
2: - int b = 2;
3: - int c = 3;
4: + int a = 0;
5:   int d = 4;
```

How can I make git-diff not display the `line 2 and 3` above? It should only output like this:

```
1: - int a = 1;
2: + int a = 0;
3:   int d = 4;
```

I am creating a script and it will be easier for me to parse the diff result if it will only show the modified line (lines that has been really updated e.g. changed some value within the line) not the deleted lines

Is this possible with git-diff? If not, are there any other option to solve this?

Comment: @phd result of that command is:

- int a = 1;
- int b = 2;
- int c = 3;
+ int a = 0;

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible since you cannot know if a pair of deletion and addition was actually a modification.

How do you know that `int a = 1` was changed to `int a = 0` and not that `int b = 2` was changed to `int a = 0`?

Let me change your patch slightly and ask you which lines you would keep:

```
-int a = 1;
-int b = 2;
-int c = 3;
+int b = 1;
 int d = 4;
```

```
-int a = 1;
-int b = 2;
-int c = 3;
+long c = 3;
 int d = 4;
```

```
-int a = 1;
-int b = 2;
-int c = 3;
+float e = 4.2;
 int d = 4;
```

```
-int a = 1;
-int b = 2;
-int c = 3;
+string name = "marc";
 int d = 4;
```